# How can I deploy a sci-kit learn model when the data in use are .csv files?

Tags: machine-learning, csv, audio, python, accelerometer

I am dealing with accelerometer data (csv) as well as audio data stored in FTP server coming from an android app. Data is loaded from FTP in my notebook for exploratory analysis to extract features from both type of files, i used libraries such as PyAudioAnalysis and Pandas. My aim is to understand the process of deploying the model i am gonna build later while keeping in mind that i rely heavily on csv files for the training.